# How to add Microsoft Sign-in to PHP web app

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, office365

I have a PHP-based web app that currently uses Google Sign-in with backend auth (see [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) for exactly how I have it working now) to register and login users to my site.

I would like to add Microsoft Sign-in with the same control flow if possible, but I can't find an explanation of whether or not this is possible and how to accomplish this. Currently, all I need is the basic profile information. I'm not looking to do anything complicated.

So is this possible and if so, how exactly do I set this all up?

Answer (score 2):

After working with some others in my area, I have a solution to this.

Basically, Microsoft doesn't have the same openID support that Google has, so in order to keep things consistent, I moved to using standard OAuth2.0 for my site.

I used the Google PHP API, but Microsoft does not have PHP support yet. Instead, I went with `thenetworg/oauth2-azure` as my oauth2 library and it works great for the v1.0 endpoint